# Case Sensitivity during Field Creation

Tags: custom-field, unique-field

I noticed something odd in the way Uniqueness is worded when creating a new field.

The two radio buttons are worded as:

- Treat "ABC" and "abc" as duplicate values (case insensitive)
- Treat "ABC" and "abc" as different values (case sensitive)

[image]

Surely, if "ABC" and "abc" are treated as duplicate values, they'd be case sensitive (i.e. sensitive to the case the user uses)? And if "ABC" and "abc" are treated as different values, they'd be case insensitive (i.e. insensitive to whether or not the user uses "abc" or "ABC")?

Seems like a typo on Salesforce's side or am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding.

"Treat "ABC" and "abc" as duplicate values" is case insensitive because it **ignores** (i.e. is insensitive to) the case the user uses when determining if it is a duplicate value.

"Treat "ABC" and "abc" as different values" is case sensitive because it **takes into account** (i.e. is sensitive to) the case the user uses when determining if it is a duplicate value.

Comment: Thanks, I was probably thinking about it too much. It's still worded pretty horribly if you ask me!

Comment: I agree to a degree. I think it would be clearer if they just dropped the case insensitive/sensitive parts.

Comment: Where it says `"Do not allow duplicate values"` then says `"Treat "ABC" and "abc" as duplicate values (case insensitive)"` is probably where I've gotten mixed up.

Answer (score 4):

No this is not the typo from salesforce side

- Treat "ABC" and "abc" as duplicate values means no matter what's the case of characters so its case insensitive
- Treat "ABC" and "abc" as different values means case of character matters here so its case sensitive

Example.

```
String  str = 'Test';
str.equalsIgnoreCase('test'); //will return true - case insensitive
str.equals('test'); //will return false - case sensitive
```